# How to Access custom terms metadata on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have been looking around and I did found about `get_term_meta()`. But this functionality is added in `4.4`, while my current work is using `4.1`. Is there any way I can access my custom terms metadata without using .

I have tried `get_the_terms(),get_term_by(),` and also `get_tags(),get_the_tags(),tag_description()` in case I misunderstood between Tags & Terms. But it definitely not a Tag since `tag_description()` did not return anything, but `term_description()` did return the right result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I just found an answer to this.

First, I made my custom taxonomy field with [From Pippins](https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/) and [From Paulund](https://paulund.co.uk/add-custom-meta-taxonomies).(These 2 are the **best source I got for Adding Custom Taxonomies Field**, and I do **Recommend** them)

So what I did with this? Certainly after I read around most people now use the new Add, Update, Delete, & Get Term Meta Functions. Which, I just realized that the functions I got from the 2 source is using `update_option()`!

So, the answer were, use `get_option()` function for this..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way to handle this without upgrading to 4.4+ is to implement your own term meta solution. I would recommend against that, as anything you create would be in conflict with WordPress core in case of a future upgrade.

If you can upgrade, I would seriously recommending going that path. If you can't, then you can look into using a Term Meta Plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-term-meta/.

Comment: I'm afraid upgrading is out of option since the project is already going too far  near completion and this problem just appear now.. Guess I will have to try to make the function then.. Thanks for your answer @bswatson .. Will post my function should I get it working..